# To check if Regexp is proper or not

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

### Scenario:

> 1. Multiple entries exists in student.txt file for different subject fields as Rollno, StudName, Subject, Marks for each student:
>
>    ```
>    <Rollno>,<StudName>,<Subject>,<Marks>
>
>    101,Santosh,maths,35
>    102,Hina,English,41
>    101,Santosh,Hindi,30
>    ```
> 2. Merge the student.txt data as per the template file (tempstud.txt) below for each student. The total for each student should be displayed
>      below at end of record.
>
>    Template:
>
>    ```
>    {Id:<Rollno>, Name:<StudName>, subject:<Subject>, marks:<Marks>}
>    ```
>
>    Santosh.101.txt
>
>    ```
>    {Id:101, Name:Santosh, subject:maths, marks:35}
>    {Id:101, Name:Santosh, subject:Hindi, marks:30}
>
>    Total : 65
>    ```
> 3. Create different files for each student , filename of this output file should be <Name><rollno.txt

Note, supposing I am changing the template file as below

```
{ marks:<Marks>-Id#<Rollno>-Name:<StudName>-subject#<Subject>}
```

I can also make changes to data files as below (changing column fields)

```
<Subject>,<RollNo>,<StudName>,<Marks>

maths,101,Santosh,35
English,102,Hina,41
Hindi,101,Santosh,30
```

> Your code should be generic enough for above changes also.

Below I have written half code and stuck in regexp, the match is not happening properly.

Please let me know what to change and if the code implementation is matching the scenario or not.

---

```
import re
import collections, logging
f = 'student.txt'
r = open(f, 'r')
r = r.read()
r= r.splitlines()
d ={}

for i in r :
    print(i)
    st = re.search(r"(?P<Rollno>\d+)\S+(?P<StudName>\w\D+)\S+(?P<Subject>\w\D+\S+(?P<Marks>\W\d+)",i,re.I)
    print(st)
    if(st):
        data = st.groupdict()
        print(data)
        Rollno =data['Rollno']
        print('here 1st: ', Rollno)
        StudName = data['StudName']
        print('here 2nd: ', StudName)
        Subject = data['Subject']
        print('here 3rd: ', Subject)
        Marks = data['Marks']
        print('here 4th: ', Marks)
        d ={'Rollno':Rollno,'StudName':StudName,'Subject':Subject,'Marks':Marks}
        print(d)
```

---

### output:

```
<Rollno> <StudName> <Subject> <Marks>
None
101 Santosh maths 35
<re.Match object; span=(0, 20), match='101 Santosh maths 35'>
{'Rollno': '1', 'StudName': '1 Santosh m', 'Subject': 'th', 'Marks': ' 35'}
here 1st:  1
here 2nd:  1 Santosh m
here 3rd:  th
here 4th:   35
{'Rollno': '1', 'StudName': '1 Santosh m', 'Subject': 'th', 'Marks': ' 35'}
102 Hina English 41
<re.Match object; span=(0, 19), match='102 Hina English 41'>
{'Rollno': '1', 'StudName': '2 Hina Eng', 'Subject': 'is', 'Marks': ' 41'}
here 1st:  1
here 2nd:  2 Hina Eng
here 3rd:  is
here 4th:   41
{'Rollno': '1', 'StudName': '2 Hina Eng', 'Subject': 'is', 'Marks': ' 41'}}-----> properly not matching wih regexp
101 Santosh Hindi 30
<re.Match object; span=(0, 20), match='101 Santosh Hindi 30'>
{'Rollno': '1', 'StudName': '1 Santosh H', 'Subject': 'nd', 'Marks': ' 30'}}-----> properly not matching wih regexp
here 1st:  1
here 2nd:  1 Santosh H
here 3rd:  nd
here 4th:   30
{'Rollno': '1', 'StudName': '1 Santosh H', 'Subject': 'nd', 'Marks': ' 30'}-----> properly not matching wih regexp
```

Comment: I think you should use `\s+` for spaces instead of `\S+`. `\S+` means get one or more chars that are NOT spaces.

Comment: (And I could not understand the modification of template you tried to state on your question, that's why I left it not making sense).

Comment: @Niloct Thanks alot for the help! I am trying to get sum or total of marks scored by each student using dict key and values and that need to be created in separte txt file. And i need to create txt file for each student with their name and roll no, so that I can do changes to any of the field(Column fields.

Comment: No problem :) I've learned `st.groupdict()` from your question, so +1 to you.

Comment: I am trying to get sum or total of marks scored by each student using dict key and values and that need to be created in separate txt file. And I need to create txt file for each student with their name and roll no, so that I can do changes to any of the field(Column fields).

Comment: It's too late in the evening here. For manipulation of data, just create a global dict (you will have to figure out a unique key for the dict, can be the concatenation of values of each row), and then you can loop through the values. For each value corresponding to an student, append the row to the student file, it's very similar to what you've done for reading the file. You can do this.

Comment: This question is rather confusing. It looks like some of the written material is a copy+paste of a homework, but the material has been interspersed with your own commentary. Trying to work out which bit was in whose voice was not easy. A couple of editors have tried to add quote blocks to make this easier to read.

Comment: However, it looks like the question stated is "could someone finish my homework", which is too broad. We want specific questions here (that are clear and understandable) so that they can be used by other people. It may be too late to repair this situation, but please make your next questions about one specific problem, rather then "help me, I am stuck".

Comment: @halfer there weren't "a couple of editors", it was only me that had to dig through her inability to post a well formatted question (since she's a newcomer). And your edit to my answer was abusive. I've already flagged this question to moderation. But thanks for the quote blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems with you regexp.

It's fixed here:

https://regex101.com/r/mEWE9F/1

Check the right panel with the detailed explanations of the modifications.

Basically, you had these mistakes:

1. `\S+` for selecting spaces and CSV delimiter (comma): you should use `\s*,\s*` which means, any whitespace on left of comma, then comma, then any whitespace on right of comma.
2. `\w\D+` for selecting a word. This selects a single char (`\w`), then one or more things that are not a digit `\D+`. You're better served with just `\w+`.
3. `\W\d+` for selecting a mark (grade). Just `\d+` is sufficient for an integer mark.

Again, check the detailed explanation on right panel of link above.

What you MUST learn from this is that:

> \d Matches any decimal digit; this is equivalent to the class [0-9].
>
> \D Matches any non-digit character; this is equivalent to the class
>   [^0-9].
>
> \s Matches any whitespace character; this is equivalent to the class [
>   \t\n\r\f\v].
>
> \S Matches any non-whitespace character; this is equivalent to the
>   class [^ \t\n\r\f\v].
>
> \w Matches any alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the class
>   [a-zA-Z0-9_].
>
> \W Matches any non-alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the
>   class [^a-zA-Z0-9_].

So, **an uppercase letter in a special sequence always selects the inverse of what the corresponding lowercase letter special sequence selects** (emphasizing because this was your major confusion).